# ReactJS - Webpack Uncaught Error: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

Below is my webpack.config.js. In the browser developer tools, getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined".

I have been trying to solve this for a while, but still can't figure out what I am missing..

I have searched alot and couldn't find a right answer for my case.

Could anyone please, help me with this?

```js
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

// Constant with our paths
const paths = {
  DIST: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  SRC: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  JS: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js'),
};

// Webpack configuration
module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(paths.JS, 'app.js'),
  output: {
    path: paths.DIST,
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(paths.SRC, 'index.html'),
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.bundle.css'),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'babel-loader',
        ],
      },

      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: 'css-loader',
        }),
      },

      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },

  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  node: {
    console: true,
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },

  devServer: {
    contentBase: paths.SRC,
  },
};
```

Comment: Are you sure you call this file via node in terminal/CMD like: `webpack --config webpack.config.js`

Comment: @VijayDev I run npm run dev and the browser is the place where I am getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. You used `target: node`. Remove this to resolve the issue.

This instructs Webpack to compile for usage in a Node.js-like environment (uses Node.js require to load chunks and not touch any built-in modules like fs or path). And when require is run in the browser, not polyfill is available, thus reporting the said error.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use parcel instead of webpack. Webpack is more complex than parcel. I was able to resolve my issue with parcel and I prefer to use parcel.

Here solution in here [How to Set Up a React App with Parcel](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-up-a-react-app-with-parcel/)